# При считывании данных с excel в python с помощью библиотеки win32com в массив, при выводе почему-то два раза выводит

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

Всем добрый день! Не понимаю почему у меня выводится два раза
logic.py:

'''

```
import openpyxl as opx

import win32com

import win32com.client

def logic():

    val1 = []
    def excel_read2():
        Excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(u'C:\\Users\\source\\DATA_MACH_0.18.xlsx')
        sh = wb.Worksheets('Лист3')
        sh1 = wb.Worksheets('Лист5')
        val = sh.Cells(2,2).value
        for i in range(3,14):
            val2 = sh1.Cells(i,2).value
            val1.append(val2)    
        print(val)
        print(val1)
        wb.Save()

        #закрываем таблицу
        wb.Close()

        #закрываем COM объект
        Excel.Quit()
    excel_read2()
  
logic()
```

'''

main.py:

'''

```
import logic
def MainFunction():

    logic.logic()

MainFunction()
```

'''

ожидаю вывод:

```
-1.25

[1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 0.85, 0.75, 0.68, 0.6, 0.5]
```

получаю:

```
-1.25

[1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 0.85, 0.75, 0.68, 0.6, 0.5]

-1.25

[1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 0.85, 0.75, 0.68, 0.6, 0.5]
```

Заранее спасибо, кто откликнется)

Comment: Может вы два раза вызываете `excel_read()` в коде и не замечаете этого? Или это прямо вот весь код?

Comment: @CrazyElf весь код)

Comment: Не может быть это весь код. Где `import`-ы? Такой код работать не будет )  Что-то тут не так. Тут всё важно, включая то, как называется ваш файл с текстом программы.

Comment: @CrazyElf просто не думаю, что в этом дело, поэтому и не добавила... сейчас добавила.

Comment: Так. Осталось узнать, что лежит в constants

Comment: Просто пока так и непонятно в чём может быть дело, могу предположить, что косяк в структуре программных файлов, но опять же ничего пока такого нет вроде.

Comment: @CrazyElf constants забыла удалить, не использую.

Comment: взгляд новичка: а не получается что функция отрабатывает 2 раза ? если в логике удалить excel_read2() то вывода не будет ? просто 1й раз вижу функцию в функции.

Comment: @Интик Это не должно влиять, потому что потом я собираюсь в logic() прописывать еще функции, но вызывать их сразу все через logic(), так можно и так уже делала) но я решила посмотреть на всякий и удалила excel_read2(), но всё так же выводит 2 раза(

Comment: для чего делается функция в функции ? может вывести тело функции и оставить только её вызов ?def fun1():return . def fun2:return .def fun 3(): fun1() fun2() надеюсь ясно написал

Comment: @Интик функция в функции для того, чтобы в дальнейшем в main не вызывать каждую функцию отдельно, а вызвать сразу этот блок logic, который будет отвечать всего лишь за работу с excel. Не очень поняла, что имеете ввиду, если просто оставить всё как есть и написать вместо excel_read2() в теле функции return, то он ругается на функцию, плюс ничего не вывело.

Comment: нашёл. у вас 2 раза вызывается логик. 1й раз майн и 2й раз после самой функции

Comment: @Интик Дааа, точно, фейспалм)) спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

функция логик вызывается 2 раза.из main.py и после самой функции.